Github repo isn't showing in back4app
I know that I need to give github permission to back4app in order to see the repo.
Somehow, I already give permission to certain repo in github but back4app is not seeing it.
I have authorized one repo months ago and it seems already, now I authorized another repo so I can create a new deployment but somehow after authorizing the repo, it's just not showing up.
Image showing github has given two repo accesses to Back4App

Image showing Back4App only see one repo which was added months ago

Anyone has idea why this is happening?
Thanks in advance for any suggestions / advices.

What happens if you uninstall the GitHub App and connect it again? Are you able to see it?

@Charles I thought of trying that but I'm afraid what if I couldn't add my first repo back then bye bye to that project too :( So thinking only try it if there aren't other ways

It should not be a problem. However, in case you face any issues, I encourage them to reach the support to assist you with that.

@Charles did send them an email with brief + link to this stackoverflow, hoping to get something back soon

@Charles guess that's the only way.  That's the only thing the support asked me to do, which do solve the issue.
